# Set ttl to Imap

Tags: hazelcast, ttl, hazelcast-imap

I have an `IMap` in hazelcast `(key, value)` with no `ttl` set at the time of `imap.put()`. Now after an event is triggered I want to set `ttl` to this particular key in the `IMap`. Since, at the time of this event I don't want to call `value = imap.get(key)` and then `imap.put(key, value, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` .
So how can I set ttl to that particular key ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no straight forward way to do it other than using `IMap` methods. However, I would like to know the reason to avoid the following calls.

```
value = imap.get(key);
imap.put(key, value, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

If you want to still achieve the result, you can resort to one of the following.

1. call `imap.set(key, value, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`, if you already have value with you. `imap.set()` is more efficient than `imap.put()` as it doesn't return the old value.
2. If you can accommodate to use one more `IMap`:  Use an additional map `ttlMap<key, Boolean>`. Whenever you need to set the ttl value for an entry in the actual `imap`, set an entry in `ttlMap.set(key, true, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` . Now, add a `MapListener` to `ttlMap` using `addEntryListener()` method. Whenver an entry from `ttlMap` is evicted, `entryEvicted(EntryEvent<String, String> arg0)` method will get called. Evict your entry from the actual `imap` inside this method.
3. If you are ready to get your hands dirty, you can modify the source in such a way that `process()` method of the `EntryProcessor`  method will receive a custom `Map.Entry` with a new method to set ttlValue of the key.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Dinesh. I didn't want to do so because I have to perform two operations on cache. However, to set ttl, I had to `value = imap.get(key)` to check if the value has been changed by some other client. So, I went with `value = imap.get(key);
imap.put(key, value, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` .

Comment: @Viveran, I got it. If you don't need old value related to the key (return value of put() ), you can use `value = imap.get(key); imap.set(key, value, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`. Depending on the size of your `oldValue`, it will give you some improvement in performance as your `OldValue` will not be sent back from the owner node to the calling node, over the network.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from version 3.11, Hazelcast `IMap` has [`setTtl(K key,long ttl, TimeUnit timeunit)`](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html#setTtl-K-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) method that does exactly this:

> Updates TTL (time to live) value of the entry specified by key with a new TTL value. New TTL value is valid starting from the time this operation is invoked, not since the time the entry was created. If the entry does not exist or is already expired, this call has no effect.